# How to write jaxb binding for different schema?

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, wsdl

I have 2 different schema in my wsdl. As you can see I have complexType and element with same name.("ArcSightLoginServiceException"). How can I write an external binding(binding.xml) to rename one them?

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://domain.login.webservices.logger.arcsight.com/xsd" xmlns:ax21="http://domain.login.webservices.logger.arcsight.com/xsd">
        <xs:complexType name="ArcSightLoginServiceException">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="ns1:Exception">
                    <xs:sequence/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.arcsight.com/logger/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://www.arcsight.com/logger/xsd">
        <xs:complexType name="Exception">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Exception" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="ArcSightLoginServiceException">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ArcSightLoginServiceException" nillable="true" type="ns0:ArcSightLoginServiceException"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
....
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating jaxb classes with naming conflicts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806716/generating-jaxb-classes-with-naming-conflicts)

Comment: @lexicore I know How to attach external binding file but my question is how can I write this jaxb binding for different schema?

Comment: Like in `<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation = "differentSchema.xsd"/>`?